# check for subset between two linked lists in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a boolean method isSubset (returns a boolean value if every element in set A is in set B and false otherwise) where method call can be written like this `setA.subsetOf(setB)`. My thought is to extract each element of setA and compare it with setB. If the first element of setA is matched with any in setB, proceeding to next element in setA to check. If all elements in setA is matched with any element from setB, method returns true, else (not all elements from setA is in setB) returns false. I already wrote the method to check for containment of an element to a linked list as followed:

```
  public boolean contain (Object target) {
      boolean status = false;
      Node cursor;
      for (cursor = head; cursor.getNext() != null; cursor = cursor.getNext()) {
          if (target.equals(cursor.getElement())) 
              status = true;
      }   
      return status;
  }
```

Since im still confused about the syntax of linked list operation, my question is how to extract each element and do the rest. Any help would be appreciated.
Node is declared

```
  public Node(Object o, Node n) {
    element = o;
    next = n;
  }
```

SLinkedList

```
  public SLinkedList() {
    head = new Node(null, null); // create a dummy head
    size = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [`Set.containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: possible duplicate of [check for subset between 2 sets stored in 2 linked lists, java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545977/check-for-subset-between-2-sets-stored-in-2-linked-lists-java). Don't repost a question that you have already asked. Instead, ask yourself why you didn't get answers, and improve your question. You've been asked several times what the Node class was, and why you didn't use java.util.set.

Comment: @GordonBailey thanks but suppose I dont use any API

Comment: @JBNizet I already updates my question but nobody seems to be interested in my question. Sorry for the repost, it is removed

Comment: You're asking how to implement something with a class we know nothing about. Show us your code. Try something. And explain why you don't use standard classes and try to reimplement your own. In your original question.

Comment: @JBNizet Im just asking for the method, just something like a pseudocode,  I want to understand this method so I dont use any API in here. I already showed the constructors for Node and SLinkedList classes, the rest are just setters and getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your contain method has a small bug in it. The for condition `cursor.getNext() != null;` should be `cursor != null;`. Doing so prevents the search of empty sets (which would cause your code to crash) as well as allowing the last Node in the list to be searched. Your code would run faster if you did `return status;` after `status=true;`

The structure for isSubset would be very similar to the loop you created; the loop would look like this:

```
for(cursor = head; cursor!=null; cursor.getNext()){
  if(setB.contain(cursor.getElement()) == false){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got a NullPointerException at the if condition

Comment: @user1986597 if that happened in your contain method, that means you're passing null as target at one point

Comment: Oh youre right, cause the 1st node after the head is a dummy node

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for checking whether set A is a subset of set B is correct. You asked "how to extract each element", but your code for `contain` shows that you already know how to traverse a linked list. So just traverse set A in the same way, and call `setB.contain(cursor)` for each element you traverse over. If that returns false for any element, return false immediately.

The problem with doing things this way is that it will be **very** slow if the lists are large. I'm guessing you are new to programming and may have never heard of "big O" notation. It's a way of describing how the performance of your algorithm will change as the size of the input data varies. Your `subsetOf` method will be O(n^2). If `setB` was stored in a hash set rather than a linked list, it would be O(n), which is *much* better.

You can learn more about this topic at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I believe @Nabou has written the code exactly like the way you said, but I got a `NullPointerException` at my `if (target.equals(cursor.getElement()))`  condition for `contain()` method.